# How to add HTML textarea tag into ckeditor widget?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I have HTML textarea. I want to add this HTML tag into ckeditor textarea.
How to add textarea tag into ckeditor widget?

Comment: Hello. You should maybe take a quick look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can update your question with code on which you are working and facing problem... ?

Comment: You need to set up js for editor. Take quick look at https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-WYSIWYG-Text-Editor-with-jQuery-Bootstrap-LineControl-Editor/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not fully understandable. From my understanding, I guess you are trying to make your text area into CKEDITOR.

You can use [CKEDITOR](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/) in different ways. Check the link to get their JS to implement 
it.

To make a text area into CKEDITOR simply use this code.

```
//how you r calling your ckeditor js depends on you. here i am using their cdn.
//and yeah height is optional.
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.10.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('id_of_textarea', {height: 150});
</script>
```